# Phase difference equation doubt

Tags: waves

I can't understand the explanation given by the book for the negative sign. Can you please explain? Thanks in advance.

From the e-book:

> **Phase difference between two points on a wave**
>
> Let us consider two simple harmonic waves travelling along OX and
>   represented by the equations
>
> \begin{align} y &= a \sin (\omega t - kx) \\ y &= a \sin [\omega t -k(x+\Delta x)] \end{align}
>
> The phase difference between them is
>
> $$ \Delta \phi = k \Delta x = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Delta x = -\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(x_2-x_1) $$
>
> where $\Delta x$ is called the path difference between these two
>   points.  Here the negative sign indicates that a point positioned
>   later will acquire the same phase at a later time.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to Physics SE. You should use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for writing math expressions.

Comment: Also the negative sign denotes a right travelling wave. You can look at this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/omqowqsbin) if you like.

Comment: I am seeking explanation for the negative sign in phase difference (Δ Ф) equation in the last sentence .

Comment: Ok. So do you understand the last sentence  "the negative sign indicates that a point positioned later will acquire the same phase at a later time."?

Comment: No . Can you please explain it?

Comment: A point positioned later (at greater $x$) would be at the same position(phase) at a later time from a point positioned before (at smaller $x$). You can see this visually on the graph. I included the points on it.

Comment: It helps to remember that f(x-a) shifts f to the right by a.

Answer (score 1):

This is a wave which is moving in the positive $x$ direction. 
This means that a crest is moving in that direction. 
So the motion of a particle at  a larger value of $x$ will be lagging behind a particle at a smaller value of $x$.
This lagging is the reason for the negative value for the phase angle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's review:

Wave 1:

$$ y_1 = \sin{(\omega t - kx)} $$

and

$$ y_2 = \sin{(\omega t -kx - k\Delta x)} $$

So that the phase difference between the two is:

$$ \Delta\phi_{reality} \equiv (\omega t -kx - k\Delta x) - (\omega t - kx) = -k\Delta x = -\Delta \phi_{e-book} $$

So the source of the minus sign is defining the meaning of "phase difference" backwards.

Nevertheless, the statement:

"a point positioned later will acquire the same phase at a later time"

is always true, because "later" has no meaning regarding points, except in the context of a wave. If the phase is:

$$ \phi(x, t) = \omega t - k x + \phi_0 $$

then the signs of $\omega$ and $k$ determine the direction of travel, which then defines "later".

For a right (left) moving wave with positive (negative) frequency, a point at larger $x$ is later and will hence achieve the same phase that a smaller $x$ point had at an earlier time.

While:

A left (right) moving wave with positive (negative) frequency, a point at smaller $x$ is later and will hence achieve the same phase that a larger $x$ point had at an earlier time.

Of course, absolute phase is never measured, and what really counts is:

$${\phi(x, t)}\mod{2\pi} $$

in which case, which wave has the larger phase is an arbitrary choice.

Is it too late to get your money back on the e-book?